# Nested If Else statements in Java and my formatting them? (Beginner)

Tags: java, if-statement

I am so sorry to bother anyone on here for this but I cannot seem to figure out why my code isn't running. I have tried searching the internet as well as my textbook but I am obviously missing something that probably staring me right in the face. Again I apologize for the simplicity of this. Any help is appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Potato
 */
public class MannPass4 
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Declerations
        double packageA, packageB;
        double aPrice = 9.95, bPrice = 13.95, cPrice = 19.95;
        double hoursA = 10, hoursB = 20, rHours, holdOption, holdHours;
        final int A_ADDIT = 2, B_ADDIT = 1;

    holdOption = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the cuctomer's package (A, B, or C):"));

    holdHours = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the number of hours used:"));

        if (holdOption == 'A')
        {
        rHours = (holdHours - hoursA);
        packageA = ((rHours * A_ADDIT) + aPrice);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The charges are "+ packageA);
        } 
        else if(holdOption == 'B')
        {
        rHours = (holdHours - hoursB);
        packageB = ((rHours * B_ADDIT) + bPrice);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The charges are "+ packageB);
        }       

        else if (holdOption == 'C')
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The charges are "+ cPrice);
        }

                else 
                {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid choice, please choose either A, B, or C.");
                }     
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Are you declaring  holdOption and holdHours?

Comment: What happens when you compile and run this code? Do you get any errors? If so, what are they. If not, what is the output and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: Why do you turn your JOptionPane double and then compare as String ?

Comment: Why do you use `Double.parseDouble()` for character input and comparing?

Comment: I get the feeling you meant to only `Double.parseDouble` on `holdHours`, but you've done it on `holdOption` as well, so your if statement is always going to drop down to the else block.

Comment: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "B"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
 at javaapplication5.MannPass4.main(MannPass4.java:26)
/Users/owner/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds)"   sorry not sure entirely what all this means but it is what pops up when I run it.

Comment: how would I use the holdOption in the output to say they picked the "package A"? I honestly wasn't sure how to grab the users input for that question.

Comment: It means that you asked the user to enter `A`, `B`, or `C`, but then proceed to call `Double.parseDouble()`, which of course fails, because it's not a number.

Comment: I see that now, but after they answer either A, B, or C; wouldn't I need to use their answer to continue the code? As in to say that they picked A which would cost them $9.95 a month for 10 hours of internet. I thought a boolean statement would work on that. if (holdOption == 'A')?

Answer (score 2):

You are parsing `holdOption` as a `double`, while it should actually be a `String`. Slightly modifying your code:

```
// Declarations
double packageA, packageB;
double aPrice = 9.95, bPrice = 13.95, cPrice = 19.95;
double hoursA = 10, hoursB = 20, rHours, holdHours;
final int A_ADDIT = 2, B_ADDIT = 1;

String holdOption = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        "Enter the cuctomer's package (A, B, or C):");

holdHours = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        "Enter the number of hours used:"));

switch(holdOption)
{
    case "A":
        rHours = (holdHours - hoursA);
        packageA = ((rHours * A_ADDIT) + aPrice);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The charges are " + packageA);
        break;
    case "B":
        rHours = (holdHours - hoursB);
        packageB = ((rHours * B_ADDIT) + bPrice);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The charges are " + packageB);
        break;
    case "C":
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The charges are " + cPrice);
        break;
    default:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Invalid choice, please choose either A, B, or C.");
        break;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I have been very confused on the idea of a String and what all it entails. Why use switch though? The only reason I ask is because the chapters we are covering have been teaching Nested If statements, but NetBeans and now you have suggested I use switch instead.

Comment: The effect of `if`/`else` and `switch` is the same. However, `switch` statements are more computationally efficient than if-else chains, especially when there are many cases. The reason for this is, that with if-else chains, the entered value is (in the worst case) compared against every possible value, which takes time. From a `switch`, however, the compiler creates a lookup table, where the program can jump to the right location right away. Therefore, I wonder why your textbook suggests using nested if-else at all. Switch is better, for the cases where it is applicable.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking time to explain this. I know it must be frustrating to explain something so simple. I honestly don't know why my textbook teaches us this either. Currently emailing my Professor to find out. Thank you again for all your help, sorry for the bother Beethoven.

Comment: My pleasure, no need to apologize :)